# RRDtool update and modify rrd data source at timestamp

Tags: linux, timestamp, datasource, rrdtool

I would to modify my `rrd` file. In particular I would modify one or more datasource data at precise timestamp.
I tried to do this with rrdtool update command but without success

Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you have tried, what the result was, and what you wanted the result to be. As it is, your question isn't exactly clear.

Answer (score 0):

RRD is an INSERT-ONLY database ... it has no built in capabilities for modifying data after inserting ... you can use `rrdtool dump` to convert the rrd file to xml format, modify the data and then use `rrdtool restore` to recreate the rrd file.

Answer (score 0):

RRDTool databases do not support update.  This is because they progressively summarise the data into the RRA, and so, as time moves on, no longer have the original raw data but only the summarised data.

In addition - and more importantly - RRD data are subject to Normalisation.  This converts the original time/value pair to an adjusted value on the precise time interval boundary.  In other words, if your interval is 5min, then a sample submitted for 12:01 will be adjusted proportionately into the 12:00 and 12:05 intervals.  So, you cannot store an exact time.

If you are looking to store a series of events with precise times and values, with the original data available and updateable indefinitely, then RRDTool is not an appropriate choice of database.  Lok at MySQL, Postgres, and other RDBMS.